# Fuzzy image on large canvas, but crisp on small

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, internet-explorer-11

I have an application, where I would like to draw some figure on the hidden canvas then stamp it on as many places as I'd like instead of drawing same figure multiple times (for better performance).
Currently figure can be drawn on floating point coordinates, same applies for stamping.
Drawing image on floating point coordinates works fine: the image is crisp and sharp. But when I copy image from other canvas to same floating point coordinates I get blurry image. **What is more interesting: it is blurry only when destination canvas has big width/height!** When destination is quite small (~20 px) resulting image is sharp (in Chrome).
So, my question:

1. Why I get blurry image in the case when destination canvas is big
2. How do I fix or get around that?

Here is the demo URL: http://the-coderok.azurewebsites.net/canvas.html 
And its code: it has 4 canvas. Source is where I draw figure which then I would stamp at rest 3.

blurrySmall - small canvas, where I copy image at floating point coordinates. It produces sharp image.

blurry - big canvas, blurry resulting image. I draw same figure at float coordinates - result is sharp.

Sharp - I copy image to int coordinates - result is sharp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=620">
  <title>HTML5 Demo: Canvas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='doDraw'>Draw</button>
  <br>
  <section>
    <canvas id ="source" width="14" height="14" ></canvas>
    <br>
    <hr/>
    <canvas id ="blurrySmall" width="20" height="20"  ></canvas>

    <br />
    <hr/>
    <canvas id ="blurry" width="839" height="839"  ></canvas>
    <br />
    <hr/>
    <canvas id ="sharp" width="839" height="839"  ></canvas>    
  </section>



  <script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('doDraw');
    btn.onclick = function(ev){
      doDraw();
    };
    /*
    xTranslation = -56.669999999999995
    yTranslation = -589.3000000000001
    */

    function doDraw(){
      var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("source");
      var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
      mainContext.beginPath();
      mainContext.arc(7, 7, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
      mainContext.closePath();
      mainContext.lineWidth =2;
      mainContext.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,127,14,1)";
      mainContext.stroke();

      var sharpCanvas = document.getElementById("sharp");
      var sharpContext = sharpCanvas.getContext("2d");
      sharpContext.drawImage(mainCanvas, 1, 1);

      var blurryCanvas = document.getElementById("blurry");
      var blurryContext = blurryCanvas.getContext("2d");
      blurryContext.drawImage(mainCanvas, 1.67, 1.3);

      blurryContext.beginPath();
      blurryContext.arc(33.67, 33.3, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
      blurryContext.closePath();
      blurryContext.lineWidth =2;
      blurryContext.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,127,14,1)";
      blurryContext.stroke();

      var blurrySmallCanvas = document.getElementById("blurrySmall");
      var blurrySmallContext = blurrySmallCanvas.getContext("2d");
      blurrySmallContext.drawImage(mainCanvas, 1.67, 1.3);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled

Answer (score 1):

The image you draw becomes a bitmap. Bitmaps are made up of pixels, and are resolution dependent. Thus each pixel will be scaled up or down depending on where you copy it. The result is that copying to bitmaps larger than the original will result in some artifacts from scaling up. Namely in this case blurry images.

To solve render the hidden image in at least the resolution of the largest canvas it will be copied to, and only scale down.

Comment: But I'm not scaling it. I'm just drawing it at given point `blurryContext.drawImage(mainCanvas, 1.67, 1.3);`

Comment: The width  and height given in the canvas tag and the resolution of the canvas are not the same. You need to match the display resolution with the canvas resolution. The result of the mismatch is the same as scaling. Also try to avoid drawing images at fractional offsets as this can result in blurry artifacts or worse. Draw at the `Math.round(1.67),Math.round(1.3)`

Comment: can you please show me how do I do that "You need to match the display resolution with the canvas resolution"?

Comment: To match the display resolution and the canvas resolution `<canvas width="128" height="128" style = "width: 128px; height: 128px;">` Use the tag height and width for display resolution and the style width and height for the canvas pixel resolution. Personally I create the canvas in javascript and add it to the page, rather than get them from the page.

Comment: I can't agree with you due to multiple reasons: 1. Canvas created on the same page in the same manner. Why would their resolution be different from each other? 2) Why image is not fuzzy when I copy it to the int coordinates? If the resolution is different, it shouldn't matter, right? 3) Why image is not fuzzy when destination canvas is small and blurry when destination is big. It looks like some black magic to me.